# how to get application name from process in android?

Tags: android, background-process, pid

i am trying to get background running applications name.  Here is my code

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> li = am.getRunningServices(100);
    for(ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo list2 : li){
        Log.d("DEBUG: ", "Background process: " + list2.process);
        Log.d("DEBUG: ", "Background pid: " + list2.pid);
    }
```

How can i take application name or package name from the above code?

do we have some other way to find background running applications name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following approach (meanwhile you should check the code because I didn't check it)

```
ComponentName mComponentName = list2.service;
Log.d("DEBUG: ", "ClassName: " + mComponentName.getClassName() + " Package: " + mComponentName.getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the package manager from li.service

ComponentName owns a method getPackageName().

You can then use PackageManager to retrieve more details about this package.